# Jquery ui.accordion error

Tags: jquery-ui, typeerror

I have a featured content slider on my homepage here: [etiquetteplus.net](http://etiquetteplus.net)

That slider loads fine in old versions of IE and FF. But new versions and with chrome it doesnt.

I get theses errors, but I am not sure what they mean.

```
ui.core.js:179Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ':' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ':' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (E,F){return new o.fn.init(E,F)} has no method 'widget'
```

I have tried newer versions of jquery but that didnt help either. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: could you please show us your code ?

Comment: Sorry, I think this is it: http://pastebin.com/pHb4AUjN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there seems to be allot going on here but the most important thing I see off hand  is on line 41 of your source code you include jquery and colorbox like so

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.etiquetteplus.net/wp-content/themes/etiquette/js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
```

then on line 86 you load a really really really old versions of jquery

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.etiquetteplus.net/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.etiquetteplus.net/wp-content/plugins/wp-faq/js/wp-faq.js?ver=2.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.etiquetteplus.net/wp-content/plugins/wp-faq/js/jquery/ui.core.js?ver=2.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.etiquetteplus.net/wp-content/plugins/wp-faq/js/jquery/ui.accordion.js?ver=2.9.2'></script>
```

i also see this error

```
Error: Error calling method on NPObject!
Source File: http://www.etiquetteplus.net/wp-content/themes/etiquette/js/sifr.js
Line: 17
```

in ff error console

then on your html is not valid

on line 210 you have a closing

```
  </a>
```

tag with no open you spans a span without close etc...

you need to make sure you are using only one version of jquery and you need to validate your html

i use [web devloper addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/) in firefox  to help trouble shoot there are all kinds of cool things to help you get a good working site in order. ff only has a built in error console that will help as well

I am sure that there are more problems that what I have shown here. but if you do diligence and comb your code and html with a fine tooth comb you will get it working correctly. If you get stuck post another question (not duplicate of course) and someone will help.

good luck
mcgrailm

Comment: I didnt realize that they were all old versions of JQ I deleted the 1.3.2 one before but it didnt help. thanks

Comment: @thegreyspot does this answer your question ? I see you accepted the my answer but have not awarded the bounty yet. bounty must be awarded separately this is explained in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty)

Comment: I just found out im still having problems with ie9, do you mind taking a quick look? thanks

Comment: what problem are you having in IE?

Comment: The slider does not load on the etiquetteplus.net page. I can't find any errors, apart from the sifr.js one, which I can't see it conflicting.

Comment: why don't you see if you can fix or remove that error and see the problem presists

Comment: Ok I removed the sifr.js files, I no longer get any errors on the page. But Ie9 still has the issue :/

Comment: what version of IE i got not problem in IE8

Comment: hmmm I don't have IE9 best thing I could tell you is to make sure all your html and javascript is valid use w3 vaidator and jslint.com